# Rails: Styling dynamically generated odd even

Tags: html, css

Screenshot below of the posts in a forum application.  I want to style the odd posts a different color from the even posts, which is the reason the forum application sets up this way.

Just to make sure I can get styling to work in general I did

```
#posts {background-color: #e8d1d1; }
```

and the whole background changed color, as expected.

However, if I do

```
.post odd {background-color: #e8d1d1; }
```

I get nothing

If I do

```
#posts .post odd {background-color: #e8d1d1; }
```

I'm also getting no styles.

In fact, even if I do

```
#posts #post_1 .post odd {background-color: #e8d1d1; }
```

I'm also getting no styles. But if that did work, it wouldn't really solve my problem because I don't want to manually enter the number of the posts (i.e. post_1 etc)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`odd` and `even` rows are style concepts and should not be implemented in Rails or HTML. Try implementing this in CSS only.

```
.post:nth-child(odd)  { /* ... */ }
.post:nth-child(even) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

`class`es on HTML tags are space delimitered, so `class="post odd"` causes the HTML tag to inherit css from both `.odd` and `.post`.

To remedy it just add an underscore to the css `.class` declaration so it becomes

```
.post_odd {background-color: #e8d1d1; }
```

then it should work.

Comment: not before, but did now. Still not working. Must be something else.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm sorry. Do you know if it is even getting loaded? Using your browser dev-tools see if it's actually getting loaded and make sure it isn't getting overridden by another CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [cycle](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle) if you want to do it the Rails way.

CSS option is better if you are going to remove / add elements between these. That way the background colors will be preserved.

EDIT::

Misread the question: This is a styling issue and not related to rails

`#posts .post.odd { background-color: #e8d1d1; }`

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I think you can remove the anchor tag since each post can be reached by the div id (i.e. #post-1, #post-2 reference the id of the div tag, not the name of the anchor tag)

Secondly, every single style you've attempted is wrong:

```
.post odd {background-color: #e8d1d1; }
```

attempts to style a tag inside of another tag with the class post.

```
<div class="post"><odd>blah blah blah</odd></div>
```

see the problem? there is no "odd" tag

Try the following:

```
#posts .post { border: 1px solid #000; }
#posts .odd { background: red; }
#posts .even { background: green; }
```

Once you get that working (no reason it shouldn't) fix the background colors (lol) and style it however you want.